# Number Formatting in Velocity Template upto atleast 2 decimal points

Tags: velocity, velocity-template-language

I have to format given character [132233.2453]  like this -> 132,233.2453

current code -> $number.format("###,###.##00", $value)

which seems to be working fine, but for character [295] -> it should be 295.00 [minimum 2 characters after decimal points] but it is coming 295 [without any decimal points]

Answer (score 0):

In Velocity, double quoted strings are interpolated. And in an interpolated string, `##` starts a line comment. So basically your formats are empty.

Also, the decimal specification should be `00##` and not `##00`.

So try: `$number.format('###,###.00##', $value)`